# Relaunch php script in case of failure

Tags: php, webserver

I have a php script launched after an http request with some POST params. 
I would that server could check if script was executed without error or not, and in that case, launch automatically again that script (with the same initial params).
How can i do it?

Comment: Write something in your script to write its status to a file, and clean up when  its done.

Answer (score 0):

On the redirected page you can use `try` and `catch` block and in the catch block redirect on another page or call appropriate function to redirect with params. But be careful on the loop in the redirect.